# How to print the multidimensional array in advanced way?

Tags: php, arrays

Following is the code

```
print_r($_POST).'<br><br>';

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
if(is_array($value))
{
    foreach($value as $key => $value)
    {
    echo "<br><br>".$key." ".$value."<br>";
    }
}
echo "<br>";
}
```

**Output is**

Array ( [Cake_on_Name] => Array ( [0] => Rachana [1] => Sarika [2] => Pratik ) [Cake_on_Date] => Array ( [0] => 2017-12-19 [1] => 2017-12-19 [2] => 2017-12-19 ) [Cake_on_Time] => Array ( [0] => 10 A.M [1] => 10 A.M [2] => 10 A.M ) [Cake_Receiver_Name] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Ashvin Ade ) [Cake_on_Address] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Amravati ) [pincode] => Array ( [0] => 444607 [1] => 444607 [2] => 444607 ) [cheu] => 1-1@500,54-1@1000,65-1@1000,54-1@300,56-1@1000,65-1@300,54-1@1000 [clientinput] => Add Detail & Buy )

0 Rachana

1 Sarika

2 Pratik

0 2017-12-19

1 2017-12-19

2 2017-12-19

0 10 A.M

1 10 A.M

2 10 A.M

0

1

2 Ashvin Ade

0

1

2 Amravati

0 444607

1 444607

2 444607

**But I Want Output as :**

0 Rachana

0 2017-12-19

0 10 A.M

0

0

0 444607

1 Sarika

1 2017-12-19

1 10 A.M

1

1

1 444607

2 Pratik

2 2017-12-19

2 10 A.M

2 Ashvin Ade

2 Amravati

2 444607

Answer (score 0):

You put it in `<pre>` tags.

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $_POST, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

---

This only displays this way in html. From the command line or if the document is formatted as plaintext, it already prints with line breaks. From a web page output, you can also do:

```
//this will also show all other content as standard text with line breaks.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

[image]

Comment: this is not expected answer.

Comment: Following output is expected

0 Rachana

0 2017-12-19

0 10 A.M

0

0

0 444607

1 Sarika

1 2017-12-19

1 10 A.M

1

1

1 444607

2 Pratik

2 2017-12-19

2 10 A.M

2 Ashvin Ade

2 Amravati

2 444607

Comment: Your question is about how to make the output readable. That is the answer for doing so. If you want a specific key, then `print_r` the specific key. If this is a homework question, [those are not allowed on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18251/187883).

Comment: This is not homework question, if you are able to solve this query, don't post   like this. #mopsyd

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable answer to your question as posed. I will flag you if you have a bad attitude about it.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: This is a site for helping you understand how to solve an underlying problem, not for a copy and paste answer to a question you don't actually want to think about.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$length = count($_POST["Cake_on_Name"]);
for($i=0; $i<=$length;$i++) {

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
echo $i ." ". $value[$i]."<br>";
}

}
```

Comment: $_POST["Cake_on_NAme"] is dynamically changeable.

Comment: You have to have some indicator of how many iterations you wanna do. If there is no Key that stays the same, you have to add it. Preferably I would add $_POST["Number_of_Rows"]. That way, you would just change $length definition to $length = intval($_POST["Number_of_Rows"])

Comment: Ok i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_map` and iterate over the result.

```
$zipped = array_map(null, ...array_values($_POST));

foreach ($zipped as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $index => $value) {
        echo $index . ' ' . $value;
    }
}
```